# Can't point subdomain to my web host

Tags: domains, subdomain, namecheap

I am trying to connect a staging website to a subdomain. My registrar is namecheap and I have followed their guide on registering a subdomain.

Here's my `CNAME Record` at namecheap with corresponding subdomain:

[image]

It said that it may take up to 4 hours to propagate, this was 2 days ago. When I set `stage1.arturmueller.com` as primary domain of my web application at cloudways and try to load the page it just says that the site can't be reached.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the cname might be backwards.  It is hard to tell from the screenshot because you didn't include the headings, but it looks like `www` points to `stage1.example.com`.  I'd think you'd want `stage1` to point to `www.example.com`.   Can you check on the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CNAME record does not look properly formed. It looks like you have `www` (`www.arturmueller.com`) pointed to `stage1.arturmueller.com`. Nothing is actually pointing your domain to the Cloudways server.

You will need to add a `CNAME` or `A` record that points from `stage1` (`stage1.arturmueller.com`) to Cloudways' server domain name or server IP address. Refer to your Cloudways account to get the domain or IP of your Cloudways server.